# Building a SELECT clause with dynamic number of columns

Tags: sql, select, join, dynamic, resultset

Is it possible to create a SELECT clause with a varying number of columns to be returned depending on joined tables?

For instance.
If I join a table depending on a value in the WHERE-clause I want to return either tbl1.col1, tbl1.col2 if tabl *tbl1* is joined or tbl2.col4, tbl2.col5, tbl2.col8 if table *tbl2* is joined.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: You can create views for each different scenario, but can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: ...you seem to want two different statements here, why not just write the queries separately.  If there is a common portion, perhaps you want a view.  Otherwise, you have to build the statement with dynamic SQL, how is up to the frameworks/application-layer language.

Comment: My question is related to my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184078

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't write one query that sometimes returns n columns and another time m columns. What you can do is something like this: Use UNION ALL on two queries with conditions that *either* query 1 *or* query 2 Returns data. Have columns match, so where one query has no value let it select null in this place.

```
select tbl1.col1 as firstname, tbl1.col2 as lastname, null as street, tbl1.col3 as job as street from ...
where @variable = 1
UNION ALL
select tbl2.col4 as firstname, tbl2.col5 as lastname, tbl2.col8 as street, null as job from ...
where @variable = 2;
```

Or you just build your SQL dynamically with whatever language and use completely different SQL, which is what one would normally do.

Comment: ...would be a nice thing to have in SQL. Thank you.